# Getting ETA to GitHub Action's completion

Tags: github, github-actions

Here is a screenshot of GitHub Actions status:

[image: GitHub Actions status]

Is there any way one can display an ETA until a GitHub Action completes?

I am imagining it somehow averages historical runtimes for a particular GitHub Action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API that comes from GitHub for this.

But you could build your own system, that caches the build times and based on that calculates the average.